# SoundCloud API: redirect url

Tags: soundcloud

Consider this example for authentication from PHP at https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication seem to suggest you can pass a redirect url as a parameter when you flow a user throught the authentication process:

```
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

// create client object with app credentials
$client = new Services_Soundcloud(
  'CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET', 'REDIRECT_URL');

// redirect user to authorize URL
header("Location: " . $client->getAuthorizeUrl());
```

Note the 'REDIRECT_URL' argument in the call to the constructor.

That seems to suggest I can pass an arbitrary redirect url as a parameter, just like you can do with Twitter (the API is quite similar).

However, if I pass an url that does not match the unique redirect url configured for the application, I get an error when the user is redirected to my url:
**error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirection+URI+provided+does+not+match+a+pre-registered+value.**

So, what is that parameter supposed to be for, if the only valid value is the redirect url configured for the application?

And **how are you supposed to handle authentication** if the user can only be redirected to a single fixed url after authentication?? That makes the API completely unusable. When you have a user login into any API (e.g. Twitter or Facebook), you need them to **be returned to the page from which they clicked the link to log in**, and it is a ridiculous restriction that that url be unique. No other social network api that I've ever seen has this restriction.

Is SoundCloud API really so flawed or am I missing something?

Comment: "No other social network api that I've ever seen has this restriction." you might not have seen it but many services do this.

Comment: "That makes the API completely unusable." No it just means you have to handle it yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question whether the SC api is flawed is highly subjective

Comment: @PeeHaa no, the question is what's the workaround

Comment: Regarding your second comment, so how am I supposed to handle it, if I want to have a link to log in into SoundCloud in several pages of my web, given that the return url is unique? If you provide an answer I'd be glad to accept it

Comment: And regarding your first comment, out of curiosity, could you name one or two other services that have this restriction?

Comment: By the way, I would have reported this as a bug on SoundCloud API's bug tracker if they had one, but they don't. Instead, they say they provide support through StackOverflow, so if this question is OT you'd have to blame them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer from Glen Scott, the author of the php-soundcloud library (a pretty decent wrapper around this terrible API) who provides a workaround. It's painful as it involves an additional redirect but it's all the API allows.

https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud/issues/36

I quote:

> The API does not allow an arbitrary URL. As you noted, this is unlike
>   most other oAuth-backed social network API's. The workaround I can
>   recommend is using the state parameter to pass back your return URL.
>   You can do this when generating the authorization URL like this:
>
> ```
>             $client->getAuthorizeUrl(
>                 array(
>                     'state' => 'http://example.com/return'
>                 ) You'll get the state parameter added to the static redirect URL. For example, if you set your redirect URL to
> ```
>
> http://example.com/callback then SoundCloud will redirect an
>   authenticated user to
>   http://example.com/callback?state=http://example.com/return
>
> Your callback script will need to look for the state GET parameter,
>   and redirect using it.